# What's the alternative synonym of “ledger”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, idioms

What's the alternative or synonym of "ledger" in below sentence?

> In a manual accounting system, each account is kept on a separate page
>   or card.  These pages or cards are placed together in a book or file
>   called the general ledger.
>   In the computerized system that most companies have today, accounts are 
>   maintained on magnetic tapes or
>   disks.
>  However, as a matter of convenience, accountants still refer to
>   the all-inclusive group of company accounts as the **general ledger**, or
>   simply the **ledger**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic tapes and disks? This sounds like ancient times!

There aren't many synonyms for something as specific as a "general ledger." I looked it up, and there are a few:

> ***book of accounts***
>
> ***books***
>
> ***ledger***

That's about it. ***Book of accounts*** is probably the closest in meaning to general ledger. ***Books*** is a very common term. If you ***keep the books*** for a company, that means you're the company's accountant. If you ***cook the books***, that's an idiom meaning you are a crooked accountant who is cheating and lying in the accounts. ***Books*** is a more general and less formal term than general ledger.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck. And ask more questions! :-)